# Why on a reference string and its reverse page faults are same by LRU and Optimal Page Replacement Algorithm?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory, lru

I was reading **Virtual Memory** from [Operating System Concepts by Galvin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118063333) and came across a statement, it says:

"**We can think of LRU strategy as the optimal page-replacement algorithm looking backward in time, rather than forward.**"

Then on the other line, it says:

"**If we let `Sr` be the reverse of a reference string `S`, then the page-fault rate for the OPT algorithm(Optimal Page Replacement) on `S` is the same as the page-fault rate for the OPT algorithm on `Sr`. Similarly, the page-fault rate for the LRU algorithm(Least recently Used) on `S` is the same as the page-fault rate for the LRU algorithm on `Sr`.**"

So if `LRU` is `OPT` looking backward in time then how come on a string and it's reverse page faults are same, because according to my understanding of the first statement: if page fault on a string S by LRU is `x` and and by OPT is `y`, then page faults on it's reverse string Sr by LRU and OPT must by `y` and `x` respectively.

Why they **must** be same everytime for every string set and it's reverse?

LRU: Least Recently Used Page Replacement

OPT: Optimal Page Replacement

Answer (score 1):

The wording is confusing, but it's not saying `pfr(LRU(S))==pfr(OPT(S))`, because that's clearly not true. It's saying that they display the same characteristics because `LRU(S)` is effectively `OPT(Sr)`, so `pfr(LRU(S))==pfr(LRU(Sr))`.

So your analysis is correct: they have different page fault rates.

Comment: Still not clear to me. You are saying that LRU(S) is effectively OPT(Sr). Then in the next line pfr(LRU(S))==pfr(LRU(Sr)). Shouldn't it be pfr(LRU(S))==pfr(OPT(Sr))

Answer (score 0):

Given that `pfr(LRU(S)) == pfr(Opt(Sr))` we can deduce that LRU will give the same page fault count on both S and its reverse Sr using the following arguments.

1. Since Optimal is the best performer, page fault count of LRU on any reference string X must be at least as many as Optimal, or `pfr(LRU(X)) >= pfr(Opt(X))`.

Applying (1) this to S we get `pfr(LRU(S)) >= pfr(Opt(S))` but since `pfr(Opt(S)) == pfr(LRU(Sr))` the LHS of this inequality can we subsituted:

2. `pfr(LRU(S)) >= pfr(LRU(Sr))`

Applying (1) to Sr (i.e substitute Sr for X) we get a similar relation

3. `pfr(LRU(Sr)) >= pfr(LRU(S))`

Now we have two inequalities in the form `A >= B` and `B >= A` which hold true only if `A == B`